# Determining the quadrant of a point

Tags: java, performance, geometry

I need to determine the quadrant of point, in a faster way. I am only aware of "determine using the signs" method. I am looking for a good approach, if any. If not any fixes to my code would help. Assume there are 4 quads on the plane. My code-

```
        int x = scan.nextInt() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        int y = scan.nextInt() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            switch (y) {
            case 1:
                quad = 1;
                break;
            case 0:
                quad = 4;
                break;
            }
            break;

        case 0:
            switch (y) {
            case 1:
                quad = 2;
                break;
            case 0:
                quad = 3;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Is this homework? Did you implement the "determine using the signs" algorithm? Is there a performance problem with it (why is it not fast enough?). Show us your code.

Comment: @Jesper Not homework. Pasted my code.

Comment: Ok, so why is it not fast enough?

Comment: I am looking for a faster approach. Just tell me if there are any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Branching and memory look ups are the things to avoid when doing micro optimizations on a snippet of code. With inline assembly you could just use the CMOV (Conditional MOV) to get a speedup on x86 systems. Java's hotspot compiler can be coaxed into using this instruction as well. But since the snippet is so simple, doing too many operations to avoid the branching or memory look ups might (in the end) be defeatist.

```
static int[] QUAD_LUT = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 3};
...
// use the sign bit on the integers
return QUAD_LUT[ (x >>> 31) | ((y >>> 30) & 0x2) ]
```

When you think about the result you're after

```
x.sign y.sign Quad
0      0      1
0      1      4
1      0      2
1      1      3
```

**You can get to the formula**

```
(x.sign XOR y.sign + y.sign + y.sign) + 1
```

**So in Java**

```
y = (y>>>31);
return ((x>>>31) ^ y) + y + y + 1;
```

**EDIT** Just for people curious about inline assembly...

```
;; NASM/FASM syntax
;; GetQuadrant(int x, int y)
;; RETURN [1|2|3|4] in EAX register
GetQuadrant:
    MOV     eax, [esp+4] ;; = x
    MOV     ecx, [esp+8] ;; = y
    SHR     eax, 31 ;; = >> 31
    SHR     ecx, 31 ;; = >> 31 
    XOR     eax, ecx ;; = x XOR y
    LEA     eax, [eax + ecx * 2 + 1] ;; = x + y*2 + 1
    RET     8 ;; correct stack and return
```

Comment: Pretty nice, congratulations!

Comment: Nice one. I did not get the idea of these operators.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method for you. Looks simple...

```
getQuadrant(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really a simple one than mine. But not faster one.

Comment: If the goal is performance, this answer isn't correct. Branching is a known performance hindrance. If the goal was best practice/clarity this is a clear winner.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] quads = new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 1 };

int x = scan.nextInt() > 0 ? 2 : 0;
int y = scan.nextInt() > 0 ? 1 : 0;

int result = quads[x + y];
```

Comment: Performance wise this is using 2 branches AND a memory look up. Using a branch-less version with a static "quads" look up would probably make it the general choice for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple! There's no need for branches, bit-twiddling, memory lookups, assembly language, or other complications.

```
int getQuadrant(int x, int y) {
    int X = (x >= 0);
    int Y = (y >= 0);
    return 3 + X - Y - 2 * X * Y;
}
```

(*Explanation*. Given `X` and `Y` as in my function, the quadrant is given by this quadratic polynomial:

```
1 * X * Y  +  2 * (1 - X) * Y  +  3 * (1 - X) * (1 - Y)  +  4 * X * (1 - Y)
```

and then if you collect terms and simplify, you get the expression I used.)

Comment: This is not JAVA. I cannot initialize int X = (x >= 0); Since the expression returns a Boolean.

Comment: Ah, well. I think this kind of thing demonstrates the advantage of [Iverson's convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) over a separate boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the bit twiddle example above - but I needed this in 3d and in C... so just in case this is useful. I'm sure this is close enough to convert to java anyway if someone needs it.

```
int
point_to_3d_quad (int x, int y, int z)
{
    static int q[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    int X = (x >> ((sizeof(x)*8)-1)) & 1;
    int Y = ((y >> ((sizeof(y)*8)-1)) & 1) << 1;
    int Z = ((z >> ((sizeof(z)*8)-1)) & 1) << 2;

    return (q[X | Y | Z]);
}
```